# MySql query BETWEEN results are what I expected

Tags: mysql, datetime

I am filtering the data by dates, using a BETWEEN query but if I filter, for example, from 2022-09-20 to 2022-09-22, the data that is recovered are only from 2022-09-20 to 2022-09-21, is skipping the last day.

This is my query:

```
SELECT Delivery.Delivery, Order.Order, Order.Remittance, Delivery.Date 
from Delivery e
INNER JOIN Order p 
on Delivery.Delivery = Order.Delivery 
WHERE Delivery.Date BETWEEN '2022-09-20' AND '2022-09-23'
GROUP BY Delivery.Delivery, Order.Order, Order.Remit 
ORDER BY Delivery.date ASC
```

Result:

```
DELIVERY ORDER REMIT DATE
1111     1111  1111  2022-09-20
2222     2222  2222  2022-09-21
3333     3333  3333  2022-09-22
```

EXPECTED:

```
DELIVERY ORDER REMIT DATE
1111     1111  1111  2022-09-20
2222     2222  2222  2022-09-21
3333     3333  3333  2022-09-22
4444     4444  4444  2022-09-23
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please show table definition. (likely unrelated but `e.Delivery = p.Delivery` should be before the `where` in an `on` clause)

Answer (score 1):

When you use `between` for dates, SQL reads them as `yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00`. You either need to include the time part or change your condition to

```
e.Date >='2022-09-20' and e.Date < '2022-09-24'
```

Comment: Exactly so. BETWEEN when used with date / time data types considered harmful.

Comment: If I do that, I have the next error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that correponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '>='2022-09-20' AND e.Date < '2022-09-22' GROUP BY e.Delivery

Comment: But I didn't know that the query brings the hours too, so if I add ` '2022-09-20 00:00:00'  AND '2022-09-22 24:00:00'`, It should work, right?

Comment: @BilbitBolson I don't think you can have `2022-09-22 24:00:00` for a date. It would just be 2022-09-23 at that point. My solution should work pending any syntax errors you might have in your code